# Long Press Triggered Multiple Cell Selection on UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uilongpressgesturerecognizer

I'm trying to implement a long press triggered multiple cell selection on a `UITableView`.
Once the multiple selection has triggerred, the selection and deselection must
continue with tableview's `didSelectRowAt` and `didDeselectRowAt` delegates.

Everything works fine except when I want to deselect the first selected cell
(the long press triggered one).

#### What I want

I want to be able to deselect the first selected cell with tableview's
`didDeselectRowAt` delegate.
But it can't be deselect unless it long pressed again.
As far as I understand, the `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` interferes with
the touch event delivery mechanism, as a result `didSelectRowAt` or `didDeselectRowAt`
is not getting called on the first selected cell. But they do get called when
the other cells are tapped.

#### What I don't want

Is to add another tap recognizer along with the long press recognizer.

#### How do I...

How would I achive this selection behaviour on the table view by using only its
delegate?

**Additional info:** To manage and keep track of selections, I implemented a simple `SelectionTracker`
class along with its `SelectionTrackerDelegate`. See the implementation code below.

Here is a minimum reproducible example implementation that I extracted from the original project.

**SimpleListItem.swift**

```swift
import Foundation

struct SimpleListItem {
    private(set) var id: Int // Used for selection tracking
    private(set) var title: String

    init(id: Int, title: String) {
        self.id = id
        itle = title
    }
}
```

**SelectionTracker.swift**

```swift
import Foundation

protocol SelectionTrackerDelegate {
    func selectionWillChange<K: Hashable>(oldSelection: Set<K>, newSelection: Set<K>)
    func selectionDidChanged<K: Hashable>(key: K, selected: Bool)
    func selectionDidEnd()
}

open class SelectionTracker<K: Hashable> {
    
    var delegate: SelectionTrackerDelegate?
    
    open var selection: Set<K> = Set<K>() {
        willSet {
            delegate?.selectionWillChange(oldSelection: selection, newSelection: newValue)
        }
    }
    
    open func changeSelection(_ k: K) {
        if selection.contains(k) {
            selection.remove(k)
            delegate?.selectionDidChanged(key: k, selected: false)
            if selection.count < 1 {
                delegate?.selectionDidEnd()
            }
        } else {
            selection.insert(k)
            delegate?.selectionDidChanged(key: k, selected: true)
        }
    }
    
    open func selectAll(_ items: [K]) {
        items.forEach({ item in
            if !selection.contains(item) {
                selection.insert(item)
                delegate?.selectionDidChanged(key: item, selected: true)
            }
        })
    }
    
    open func deselectAll() {
        selection.forEach({ item in
            selection.remove(item)
            delegate?.selectionDidChanged(key: item, selected: false)
        })
        if selection.count < 1 {
            delegate?.selectionDidEnd()
        }
    }
    
    open func isSelected(_ k: K) -> Bool {
        return selection.contains(k)
    }
    
    open func hasSelection() -> Bool {
        return !selection.isEmpty
    }
    
    open func selectedCount() -> Int {
        return selection.count
    }
}
```

**ViewController.swift**

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate,
UITableViewDataSource, SelectionTrackerDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!
    
    private let identifier = "simpleTableCell"
    private var data: [SimpleListItem] = []
    
    private lazy var selectionTracker: SelectionTracker<Int> = {
        let st = SelectionTracker<Int>()
        st.delegate = self
        return st
    }()
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        tableview.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: identifier)
        
        let lpgr = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(onLongPress(_:)))
        lpgr.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        iew.addGestureRecognizer(lpgr)
        
        for i in 1...20 {
            let item = SimpleListItem(id: i-1, title: "Simple cell \(i)")
            data.append(item)
        }
        tableview.reloadData()
    }
    
    
    // MARK: - TableView Data soruce delegate
    func tableview(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }
    
    func tableview(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier, for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = data[indexPath.row].title
        ccessoryType = selectionTracker.isSelected(data[indexPath.row].id) ? .checkmark : .none
        return cell
    }
    
    // MARK: TableView delegate
    func tableview(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("didSelectRowAt \(indexPath)")
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark
    }
    
    func tableview(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("didDeselectRowAt \(indexPath)")
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .none
    }
    
    
    // MARK: - Long press handling
    @objc func onLongPress(_ longPressRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
        if longPressRecognizer.state == .began {
            let touchPoint = longPressRecognizer.location(in: tableview)
            if let ip = tableview.indexPathForRow(at: touchPoint) {
                print("onLongPress: IndexPath \(ip)")
                // Trigger multiple cell selection
                selectionTracker.changeSelection(data[ip.row].id)
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    // MARK: - Selection delegate
    func selectionWillChange<K>(oldSelection: Set<K>, newSelection: Set<K>) where K : Hashable {
        // TODO: Handle selection change
        if oldSelection.count == 0, newSelection.count == 1 {
            // ie. show a menu if it is first selection
        }
    }
    
    func selectionDidChanged<K>(key: K, selected: Bool) where K : Hashable {
        // Change the cell's selected state
        if let k = key as? Int,
            let index = getIndex(for: k),
            = tableview.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)) {
                print("selectionDidChanged \(index)")
                cell.setSelected(selected, animated: true)
                cell.accessoryType = selected ? .checkmark : .none
            }
    }
    
    func selectionDidEnd() {
        // TODO: Handle selection end; ie. hide the menu
    }
    
    private func getIndex(for key: Int) -> Int? {
        return data.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == key })
    }
}
```

**NOTE 1**
The table view is configured with multiple selection and the view controller
delegated for data source and table view delegate in the interface builder.

**NOTE 2**
I also tried to implement long press triggered multiple cell selection using `UITableView.setEditing()` method. It did entered the multi selection mode, some check boxes appeared on the left side of the cell, however when I tap to select the cells, none of the cells were getting checked with the checkmark.